# Does storing ground coffee in the fridge preserve its flavor better?

Tags: nutrition, marketing, coffee

I'm Italian and, as you know, we make a big deal out of coffee.

I found some people to be very much convinced that ground coffee preserves its taste better when stored in the fridge. On the other hand, there's a whole lot of other people claiming the exact opposite.

The [National Coffee Association](http://www.ncausa.org/i4a/pages/index.cfm?pageid=70), suggests *airtight and cool* but it discourages the refrigerator, in order to avoid the contact with moisture. But if the container is airtight, shouldn't this issue be greatly mitigated? The fridge looks like a great candidate for the *cool* requirement, and an airtight container seems to be a good solution to the moisture issue.

Another downside, as mentioned [in this article](http://www.brewplus.com/coffee/how-to-store-your-coffee-powder-some-obvious-tips-and-pointers/), is that coffee tends to catch odors. Again, this issue can be easily overcome with the help of a sealed container.

On the other hand, Lavazza (a big Italian manufacturer of coffee products) explicitly advises to keep the coffee *in the fridge in an airtight opaque container* in a *Tip for freshness* section on its packages. (click to see the full-size picture)

[image]

However, I couldn't find satisfying scientific support to either claims.

Is storing coffee in an airtight container in the fridge the best way to preserve its flavor?

Comment: You could also try this question on [Seasoned Advice](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/), the network's cooking site. Yeah, we consider beverages on topic there.

Comment: @derobert thanks, I'll give it a shot in case I don't get any answers here.

Comment: Regarding the airtight container / moisture when refrigerated part - I suspect they mean that if the temperature of the container drops *too much*, moisture already present in the air inside the container will [condense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condensation), ruining your coffee.  Basically, cold air has a lower capacity to retain water, so I guess you want it cool, but not cold (unless you can expel the moisture prior to storage).

Comment: Good heavens, my friend! If you consider coffee important, what in the world are you doing with *pre-ground* coffee? No matter *how* you store ground coffee, it's going to lose its oils once it's not vacuum-sealed. (Open a fresh bag/can beside one that was opened and resealed for 2 weeks -- you'll see.) Switching to grinding your own coffee (takes 20 seconds) is probably the single biggest quality jump there is (short of moving next door to a roaster).  (Even roasted whole-ground coffee loses its oils and flavors, but not as rapidly.)

Comment: @LarryOBrien it's more a cultural thing. Pre-ground coffee is the most common to find in Italy and it can be found in almost every kitchen. Despite that, there's a lack of consensus on where to store it, hence my question. I like coffee, but I'm not maniacal, rather just curious :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is some evidence that refrigeration can help preserve aromas

[K. MARIN et al.: New Aroma Index for Aroma Quality of Coffee During Storage, Food Technol. Biotechnol.](http://hrcak.srce.hr/index.php?show=clanak&id_clanak_jezik=48135) ISSN 1330-9862 
(FTB-1827)

> The samples stored in a
>   refrigerator preserved their aroma for a longer time,
>   with decreased staling rate

...

> For consumers,
>   an alternative to preserving their roasted coffee in
>   airtight packages is to store it in a refrigerator.
>
> The staling of coffee was found to be the result of
>   evaporation or degradation by oxidation of important
>   coffee odourants, such as 2-methylpropanal, 3-methylbutanal,
>   2,3-butanedione, 2-methylbutanal, methanethiol
>   and 2-furfurylthiol, rather than of formation of off-flavour
>   compounds.

---

A study that might be slightly less relevant but whose conclusions seem at least consistent with the notion that lower temperatures preserve flavor.

[EFFECT OF STORAGE CONDITIONS ON THE SENSORY
QUALITY OF GROUND ARABICA COFFEE](http://www2.hcmuaf.edu.vn/data/lhquang/file/Coffee/Effect%20of%20storage%20conditions.pdf)

> The results indicate the importance of proper
>   storage of ground coffee and the idea that freezer storage may be more
>   effective at retarding some of the attribute changes during storage.

Comment: Thank you for finding the two studies! Very interesting read, indeed!